# Problem with anaconda environments not recognising packages

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, environment, mnist

I'm attempting to do the MNIST image classification via tensorflow and am having some trouble with packages. My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
image_index = 7777
print(y_train(image_index))
plt.inshow(x_train(image_index))
plt.show()
```

I made an environment in Anaconda-Navigator with matplotlib, tensorflow, and numpy. I then launched this env in terminal and navigated to my above code (I made sure the terminal was in bash). When running in terminal

```
python3 filename.py
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Looks like your environment doesn't have matplotlib. If you believe the contrary please prove it.

Comment: try `conda list` in the environment and confirm that indeed `matplotlib` exists

Comment: My environment does have matplotlib, it is listed in `conda list ` .

Answer (score 0):

I installed the package with pip. 
pip install matplotlib work for me.

Your code has some error.

Update your code to:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
image_index = 7777
print(y_train[image_index])
plt.imshow(x_train[image_index])
plt.show()
```